# MySQLi Select hashtag from table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to select trending #hashtags from a table and echo the hashtags in a div with MySQLi and PHP. Something that works like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM 'submissions' WHERE 'text' LIKE '%' # '%' ");
$query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if($query_run && mysqli_num_rows($link, $query_run)>=1){
echo the hashtag
}
```

Let me know if it's possible, if additional information is needed, or if I should probably have my PHP code submit caught hashtags into a unique table and have them selected from there.

Comment: With the way you wrote you query, your users would have to be entering ` # someTag` in order for it to be found later. Notice the literal SPACEs `[literalspace]#[literalspace]someTag`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query as written will not work.  Using single quotes in SQL only for string delimiters.  Try this:

```
"SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE text LIKE '%#%' "
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect, but just trying to improve, wouldn't be better use a regular expression in the select? That way you wouldn't get expressions like '#' 'bleh#' or '##'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: @Chococroc . . . The logic in the answer follows the logic in the original question.  You are correct that there might be improved detection methods, but the OP gives no sample data for determining if that is necessary.

Comment: The correct SQL is "SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE body LIKE '%23%'" because browsers pickup hashtags as %23